# Why doesn't the array keep its values outside of forEach block?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, foreach, block

Note: Inside forEach block the UserInfo array  contains a value

```
    const UsersInfo = []

     // product.users it's array
   
      product.users.forEach(async(u)=> {

        console.log(u.userID)
        us =await User.findOne({_id: u.userID})
         
    })
    console.log(UsersInfo)
```

Comment: Aside from the duplicate: You don't modify the array inside the loop.

Comment: Note that idiomatic JS reserves variable names starting with capital letters for classes / constructor functions. It isn't a great idea to use that naming convention for an array.